# "What prone position used FOR IN medicine?" Is "for in" grammatical?

Tags: prepositions

Is using the preposition "for" before the preposition "in" correct?

> What prone position used **for in** medicine?

Comment: _for_ here comes **before** _in_, not after. Why are you asking about after?

Comment: I wanted to edit and add a better title, but your question is unclear. Can you please respond to J.R.'s comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you mean your example to say is

> What is the prone position used for in medicine?

*For* and *in* do not form a unit; they are only together by chance. Each heads a preposition phrase which modifies the verb *used*. Consider the answer to this question:

> In medicine the prone position is used for [something].

*In medicine* defines the field or discipline you are concerned with and *for [something]* defines the purpose behind using the prone position.

In a question, *what* points to the missing [something] you want to know about. In the most formal English you would ask:

> For what is the prone position used in medicine?